# Webpack dev server Proxy is not working - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want run my project on localhost:3000/upct/ROUTES

But I have my API in: http://desarrollo.com/api

I wanna use proxy option in Webpack but it is not working. I get error of CORS and others... My proxy config looks like:

```
    CONFIG.devServer = {
        //host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '/api/**': {
                target: 'http://desarrollo.com/api',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        },
        contentBase: PATH.join(__dirname, '/src'),
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true/*,
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
        }*/
    };
```

I do my AJAX querys like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://desarrollo.com/api",
        data: "",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
    })
    .done((respuesta) => {
        console.log(respuesta);

    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("XHR: ", xhr/*.responseText*/, "Text Status: ", textStatus + '\n' + "Error Thrown: ", errorThrown);
    })
```

I supposse proxy is for doing AJAX querys into my API without CORS errors. But it is not working. What is wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using proxy, you have to send your requests to the `localhost`, so that proxy could redirect them to remote server without CORS. In your `$.ajax()` pass `url: "/api"`.

After that when you run your app locally your requests will be sent to `http://localhost:3000/api` and when it runs on `http://desarrollo.com` it will send requests to `http://desarrollo.com/api`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I did that. My API is done with Laravel + CAS + Apache2. As I need an API subroute (/api/perfil) I did that AJAX (url='/api/perfil') but I continue having CORS error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://autentica-des.upct.es/cas/login?service=http%3a%2f%2fingeniaticupct.ddns.net%2fapi%2fperfil%2fapi%2fperfil. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.` Thank you.

Comment: In your webpack config you showed a proxy for `http://desarrollo.com`. But the error you are showing now comes from `https://autentica-des.upct.es`. I think there is some other request you make from your localhost, that isn't proxied

Comment: Yes. `http://desarrollo.com` is were is hosted my API. When I call `http://desarrollo.com/api/perfil` I have a service which connect to CAS and returns me my personal data.

Comment: OK, but it seems you make a request to CAS directly from client, not from proxy. You need to make another proxy for this domain. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Hmm, but before that, could you show exact code, how that request was made? The one that goes to `https://autentica-des.upct.es`

Comment: $.ajax({
            url: "http://desarrolo.com/api/perfil",
            data: "",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
        })

That is my AJAX. When I into this service, if I am logged on CAS i get data, if I am not logged in CAS, redirect me to CAS Login, and returns Data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145150/discussion-between-gprost-and-jumogar).

Answer (score 0):

To add more to @GProst response, Below changes will work.

**Find Protocol :**

```
this.protocol = () => {
        let returnValue = 'https://';
        if (location.protocol !== 'https:') {
            returnValue = 'http://';
        }
        return returnValue;

};
```

**Find Hostname :**

```
const hostName = window.location.hostname + (!window.location.port === false ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
```

**Required URL :**

```
const URL = this.protocol() + hostName;
```

Now Above URL can be used in Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    data: "",
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
})
```

This will work in both **webpack-dev-server** as well as in application server e.g. **Apache**.

Comment: I added it on top of my webpack config file but I gen an error on `npm run serve`. Thank you.